# Snackbar flickers if android:animateLayoutChanges is true on root layout

Tags: android

It seems like a simple Snackbar message looks pretty jarring if `android:animateLayoutChanges` is set to `true`. The Snackbar will flicker repeatedly throughout the animation. Removing the `android:animateLayoutChanges` parameter from the layout solves this issue but now I won't get to enjoy the benefits from it. It also works if I use `android:animateLayoutChanges` on a child view instead of the root view.

Is this a known issue and is there a way around it?

Here is an example layout which will demonstrate the issue if a snackbar is shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="4dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:tint="@color/colorWhite" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an open bug. see [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/648)

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me too, still not fixed of 30/07/2021.

If applicable, the simplest workaround would be to put the part of layout that needs animating in a extra `FrameLayout`, for example like this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    
    <-- Other views here, FragmentContainerView, AppBarLayout, ... -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    
        <-- Place anything that you want animated here -->

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you would happen to have some other container views in the "useless" `FrameLayout` you may get "UselessParent" prompt by Android Studio, you can just include this ignore in the child of the added `FrameLayout`: `tools:ignore="UselessParent"`.